# Include plugin´s table in custom query

Tags: customization, query

I rephrased the question, following the suggestions of the contributors (below) helping on it.

As we know, WordPress search by default only incudes in this search function de wp_posts database table.

Following the Keyword Search in Plugin Table section in “[Custom Queries WordPress CODEX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Keyword_Search_in_Plugin_Table)" I need to join the wp_usermeta table with the wp_posts table.

I used the functions.php in child theme for these purpose of trying to join the the wp_usermeta table with the wp_posts table in order to have its data displayed.

Specifically, my need is to fetch and display in the search results the “country” field stored from the meta_key “country” in the wp_usermeta table.

I have tried the two codes below, without success. All I get is “No results”, including the posts that display fine before I include any the two below codes in functions.php.

Please advice on this.

Thanks

CODE 1:

```
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( is_search() ) {    
    $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->wp_zyus_usermeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->wp_zyus_posts. '.ID = ' . $wpdb->wp_zyus_usermeta. '.post_id ';
}

return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );
function cf_search_where( $where ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( is_search() ) {
    $where = preg_replace(
        "/\(\s*".$wpdb->wp_zyus_posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
        "(".$wpdb->wp_zyus_posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->wp_zyus_usermeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
}

return $where;
}
       add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );

  function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
global $wpdb;

if ( is_search() ) {
    return "DISTINCT";
}

return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

CODE 2:

```
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'acme_search_submission_join' );      
function acme_search_submission_join( $join ) {
if ( is_admin() || ! is_search() ) {                
          return $join;         
          }
          global $wpdb;         
          $join .= "JOIN $wpdb->wp_zyus_usermeta ON $wpdb->wp_zyus_posts.ID = $wpdb->wp_zyus_usermeta.wp_zyus_posts_id ";
          return $join;             
          }
```

Comment: "write a feature for me for free" is not a question. What have you actually tried, what concepts or APIs you find hard to understand?

Comment: `wp_usermeta` is not generated by a plugin, it's a core table.

Comment: I have improved the question to be more specific. Not intention for anyone to write a feature for me, rather than explain the architecture of the 2 methods (JOIN and pure SQL). Thanks

Comment: Here is  the CODEX for a similar need https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Keyword_Search_in_Plugin_Table but it does not provide the architecture. I understand the code of it, but no refrence to the APIs, files to use and folders to save them. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should back up 10 steps and explain in better detail what you are trying to build, and ignore what you *think* the answer might be. What is the point of searching only the user meta table? That is data that belongs to individual users. You say JOIN or SQL- JOIN *is* SQL. What are you trying to JOIN, you said there are no other tables involved? You mention posts_where filter- what does your user meta table have to do with the posts table?

Comment: Milo you are right; the plugin doesn´t add the table; it just adds the meta_key “country.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage U-Design
 */
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
get_header();
include('scripts/search_excerpt/ylsy_search_excerpt.php');
$search = $_GET['s'];
$all_users = new WP_User_Query(
array(
    'role' => 'dc_vendor',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => '_vendor_country',
            'value' => $search,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    )
)
);
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($all_users);
//echo '</pre>';
?>
    <div id="content-container" class="container_24">
        <div id="main-content" class="grid_24">
            <div class="main-content-padding">
                <?php udesign_main_content_top(is_front_page()); ?>
                <?php
                if ( ! empty( $all_users->results ) ) {
                    foreach ( $all_users->results as $user ) {
                        echo '<p><a 
href="http://www.example.com/vendor/'.$user->user_nicename.'">' . $user->display_name . '</a></p>';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'No users found.';
                }
                wp_reset_query(); ?>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php udesign_main_content_bottom(); ?>
            </div><!-- end main-content-padding -->
        </div><!-- end main-content -->
    </div><!-- end content-container -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
<?php
   get_footer();
```

No need to JOIN the usermeta table.